# When adding a file to a folder, how to make it not default save in Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script

In my script I have template docs in the main drive, but when the copy is created and populated with my excel data, I want it to be saved in a folder in drive.  I have the script do that, but it has one copy of the file in the Main Google Drive, and the other in the folder I want it in.  If I delete one of the copies, it deletes both.

Is there any way I can have it save automatically in the specified folder without also being in the main drive folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Folders in Google drive are not exactly like forders in a computer : having the file in your 'root' folder and in another folder doesn't mean there are 2 files, but rather 1 and only file with 2 labels... that's why you can't delete one without deleting the other !

The solution is simply to play with these labels in the script, here is how it works : (I commented each step to make it clear.)

```
function othertest(){
folder=DocsList.createFolder("MyFolder"); // or getFolderById or whatever other way to get your target folder
var file=DocsList.createFile('File2', 'Empty');// just an empty file for test but this would be your file copy that you want to "move"
file.addToFolder(folder);// put it in the folder
file.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());// and remove from the root
}
```

The other possible solution is to create the file directly in the target folder since the folder object supports the `createFile` method. (Not sure though that you can do it in your specific use case)

here is an example, you can see that the file is not in the root folder.

```
function createFileinFoldertest() {
   var folder = DocsList.getFolder('test')
   folder.createFile('Empty test fileName','nothing in there')
}
```